# How to extract only one capture group using regex for pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Python beginner here. I am struggling to use regex for pandas. I have a rows like this that need to split up into a column containing only the number.

```
rando45m text78 here 123  $    1   0% text here  5 . 6&
```

I need it to be displayed as

```
     0    1    2   3 
0   123   1    0   5
```

I have used the following 2 methods

```
df2 = df.Keep.str.extractall('(\d+)((\s+)|(\%))')

df3 = df.Keep.str.extractall(r'(?<=\s)(\d+)(?=\s+|\%)')
```

df2 includes the whitespace in the cell. df3 errors out for an assertion error. 
Is there a way where I can only capture one group /1 for my dataframe?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `r'(\d+)'` ?

Comment: Or `r'(?<!\S)(\d+)(?=[\s%]|$)'`

Comment: Edited the input string. text contains some digits as well.  r'(?<=\s)(\d+)(?=\s+|\%)' gives me the same error as df3 '1 columns passed, passed data had 6 columns'

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
In [39]: df
Out[39]:
                                                      Keep
0  rando45m text78 here 123  $    1   0% text here  5 . 6&
1         aaa 101.5% here 123  $    1   0% text here  55 .

In [40]: df.Keep.str.extractall(r'\b(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s|%|$)').unstack()
Out[40]:
           0
match      0    1  2  3     4
0        123    1  0  5  None
1      101.5  123  1  0    55
```